# i have an error python OOP. Python magic method __div__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-object, python-development-mode

I have "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: " for this code

```
class add_object:
    def __init__(self, num) -> None:
        self.x = num
    def __div__(self, other):
        return (self.x / other.x)
n1 = add_object(24)
n2 = add_object(12)
print(n1 / n2)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Full Stack Web Development (Python and JavaScript)\Python Django\OOP Project\Basic to advanced oop\OOP-L16.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(n1 / n2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'add_object' and 'add_object'
```

Comment: `__div__()` has no particular meaning as the name of a method.  To implement division of your custom class instances, you want `__truediv__()` (or `__floordiv__()` for the `//` operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__truediv__`. Python 3 split between `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__` for true float division and integer (floor-rounded) division respectively.

Comment: `__truediv__` is working